# Collect 3rd level data dependent on the first two

Tags: php, recursion, big-o, nested-loops

I usually don't like to give up but it feels like this could be more efficient, but for the life of me I can't see it.

I have a Webservice from which I can request the Models, Makes and Types of Cars.

But to be able to request the Types I need the Makes and to be able to request the Makes I need the Models...

Because I need ALL Types (last level) to iterate over them and use them in a different piece of functionality I need to make these 3 steps.

The only problem: my current code takes about 3 minutes to finish and it feels incorrect because of Big O..

If you guys could make this more efficient I would be forever gratefull:

```
$cars = [];
$makes = getMakes()['makes']['Make'];
$models = [];
$types = [];
$allTypes = [];

$timeStart = microtime(true);
// Takes waaaaaay too long
foreach ($makes as $key => $make) {
    $cars[$key]['makeName'] = $make['makename'];
    $cars[$key]['makeCode'] = $make['makecode'];

    $models = getModels($make['makecode'])['models']['Model'];
    foreach ($models as $subKey => $model) {
        if (is_array($model)) {
            if (array_key_exists('modelname', $model)) {
                $cars[$key]['models'][$subKey]['modelName'] = $model['modelname'];
            }
            if (array_key_exists('modelcode', $model)) {
                $cars[$key]['models'][$subKey]['modelCode'] = $model['modelcode'];
            }

            $types = getTypes($model['modelcode']);
            foreach ($types as $ssKey => $type) {
                if (is_array($type)) {
                    if (array_key_exists('typecode', $type)) {
                        $cars[$key]['models'][$subKey]['types'][$ssKey]['typeCode'] = $type['typecode'];
                        $allTypes[] = $type['typecode'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$timeEnd = microtime(true);
print_r(($timeEnd - $timeStart) / 60); // 3.228285531203 (~3 minutes)
// print_r($cars);
```

Comment: what is the implementation of getMakes(), getModels() and getMakes()?

Comment: just an api call to get the information based on the code I receive from the array (makecode and modelcode), I can edit the question to add the full functionality, it won't really give you much more info though

Comment: then let's try from the other side :) what are you using the data for and how often does the data in your datasource changes. 
What you could do is make a periodic check that gets the data from the source and store/cache it localy in a format that you can query more effectively.

Also I'm assuming here that the api calls are where the majority of the time is spent, maybe it would be a good idea to measure that, just to be sure.

Comment: it basicly is a script that will only run once for a big import. but because I want to learn from my mistakes I was wondering if it could be optimized

Comment: If the API requires you to supply the make in order to query for the models and the model in order to query for types, there is no real alternative than nested looping AFAIK.
Maybe someone else can enlighten us both :)